# How to use previous values of calculation as the initial conditions in ABAQUS

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to implement a subroutine in ABAQUS.

It is a very simple non-linear elastic model, in which the Young's modulus depends on the mean pressure, in details, `E=3*(1-2*poisson)*p/kap` (where, `poisson=0.3` is Poisson's coefficient and `kap=0.005` is swelling index).  The initial stress is 1e5 Pa for sigma11, 22 and 33.

When I run the subroutine , it gives linear behavior with  `E=3*(1-2*0.3)*(3*1e5/3)/0.05` (which is the Young's modulus calculated with the initial stress). If the initial stress is 0 for all components, it gives us 0 for all calculation because `E=3*(1-2*0.3)*(3*0/3)/0.05=0`.

I would like to ask if you could help me to solve this problem (define the initial conditions as the previous values for each variables).

Comment: Not sure I exactly understand, is this a UMAT subroutine?.  If you need the stress from the previous solution increment you need to store that yourself as a solution dependent variable.

Comment: the zero issue is a fundamental problem with your model. Are you modeling a gas or something?  Maybe putting `(p+10**5)` right in the `umat` code is the best approach, though hard to say w/o seeing the whole problem

Comment: Yes, it's an UMAT subroutine. I tried to restore the value of p=1/3*trace(STRESS TENSOR) in STATEV after each calculation. However, in the next step, the program calculates the value of E with the initial value of p (in this case, p=1e5 Pa). I don't understand why. Do u have any idea about this? Thanks so much for your reply. Best wishes!!